# Web scraping and eliminating duplicate rows

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping

I have some information I have web scraped and when I try to merge the 2 tables it is creating mass amount of duplicate rows. Both tables are 4207 X 26, and I am hoping to take about 10 columns from the 2nd table and add it to the first. I have tried a few different methods but have always received duplicate rows. I am wondering if there is a way to eliminated repeats if both "TEAM" and "Year" are repeated. Any thoughts or input would be greatly appreciate!

```
mlb_df = mlb_bat_df.merge(mlb_pitch_df[['Year','RA/G','ERA','CG','tSho','SV','IP',
                              'H_A','R_A','ER','HR_A','BB_A','Ks','WHIP','SO9','HR9','PAge']],on='Year')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
mlb_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['TEAM','Year'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: That did not seem to work. I'm not sure why, but it seemed to eliminate the entire DF. Thanks for the idea though

Comment: Did you run that code after the last mlb_df line? The drop_duplicates function should only drop duplicate values based on the subset provided, so if there's a row with the same team name and year, it will drop the repeats while keeping the first instance. Without seeing the rest of your code or the raw data, it is hard to figure out what is happening.